# From what distances do the atoms in you come from?

Tags: star, galaxy, cosmology, distances, big-bang-theory

If the atoms of a human come from stars, comets, nebulas and magnetrons, then what is the greatest distance that two atoms of a human can possibly have been away from each other previously? Perhaps the distance could be further than 4 million light years, because two galaxies further than Andromeda could have fallen into the Milky Way in the earlier universe? is that correct?

Am I way off? Could it be 5 billion light years?

Comment: When the hydrogen atoms formed, so about  3-20 min after the big bang

Comment: The universe was about 20 light years at when the hydrogen atoms formed. There's a number compared to the size of the universe and a number compared to today's distances.

Comment: FWIW, Wikipedia has a nice table of the [major elements in the human body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_the_human_body#Elements), giving percentages in both mass and number of atoms.

Comment: Sort of related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16311/16685 Also see this [periodic table indicating the origins of the elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_nucleosynthesis#Key_reactions).

Comment: I had no idea that my [magnetron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavity_magnetron) was making human atoms, no wonder my food tastes so funny!

Comment: There are [Extragalactic cosmic rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extragalactic_cosmic_ray#ref_3) that may be from far away, but their flux is quite low, so you might not have any in you.

Comment: @keithMcClary Yes indeed, so the early solar system would have had extragalactic  10^12 cosmic rays per m2 when it was planetesmals. That can be an answer, it suggests that some of our atoms come from very far away.